# Fullcalendar with asp.net mvc not showing events

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, fullcalendar

I'm trying to fetch events from my database.

```
events: {
    url: "/Planning/Planning/GetEventsUnit/@ViewBag.Unit.Code/",
    method: 'POST',
    failure: function() {
        alert('Erreur dans la récupération des événements !');
    },
},
```

No error message. The JSON response seem to be correct.

```
[{"id":3,"start":"2019-08-30T09:00:00","end":"2019-08-30T14:00:00","ressourceId":"12345678"}]
```

When i try to declare event in the code instead of database query, like this:

**EDIT [2019/09/07] : ressourceId instead of resourceId, error while i wrote the post**

```
events:[
  {
    id: 3,
    start: "2019-08-30T09:00:00"
    end: "2019-08-30T14:00:00" 
    resourceId":"12345678"
  },
],
```

It's work.

If someone could give me a little help it would greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ressourceId` needs to be `resourceId` or else fullCalendar won't recognise it. But you've made that mistake in both examples, including the one which works, so presumably it can't be that which is the issue.

Comment: By the way, which version of fullCalendar are you using? The latest v4, or an older version?

Comment: What is the `@ViewBag.Unit.Code` in your code?Do you have errors in browser by pressing F12?

Comment: @ADyson Sorry for the delay, that's the problem... ressourceId instead of resourceId in the database. It's so simple that I have not seen it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I test your code and it all works well.You need to have the `POST` action like:

```
[HttpPost("/Planning/Planning/GetEventsUnit/{code}")]
 public JsonResult Test(int code,DateTime start,DateTime end)
 {
   //logic
 }
```